# Save text files with a different extension in r

Tags: r, text-files, file-extension

I'm trying to write out an R output to a text file that is not saved as .txt but as some other unique identifier (for example .prt). I know that's possible with matlab, but I don't know how to get that to work with R.

I can't find any package to do that, and when I try to specify the extension in the file name it give me an error and doesn't save.

Any idea would be greatly welcome! Thank you.

Comment: What code exactly are you using? Any standard R output for text (`cat`,`write.table` etc) will allow you specify the filename and extension no problems.

Comment: `write.table(data, file = "data.prt")` won't work?

Comment: I don't know why but I tried exactly that before and it didn't work with my output...so I thought the simple way wouldn't work. But I changed the fiel I was trying to save and it worked. The previous file class was "data.table" "data.frame", and not a matrix, so maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using some specialized package, a lot of standard R functions for writing data to files have a `file=` parameter (or similar) to let you specify whatever the filename (and extension) you want. For example:

```
dummy.data <- matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5)

### in reality you could just write file="dummyfile.prt" as one string
### but for demonstration purposes, you can use paste0() or paste(,sep='')
### to create a new file name using some variable prefix and your extension
### ".prt"
### sep='\t' makes the output tab-delimited
write.table(dummy.data,file=paste0("dummyfile",".prt"),sep='\t')
```